# Can you paint frosted glass with mirrored paint?

Tags: doors

I need a full length mirror in my dressing room! My closet doors are frosted can I paint over them with mirror paint?

Comment: Doesn't mirror paint go on the back side of the glass?

Comment: Depending on the style of the doors, you may be able to mount a mirror over the frosted glass. You might want to consider acrylic (or other plastic) mirror as it's lighter and less prone to break, though you do have to be more careful not to scratch it when cleaning it. Also, old optics note - a "full length" mirror only needs to be half as tall as you (or as you can reach, if you want to look at you with your arms up over your head) to show all of you, if mounted at the proper height. Much more will normally be of little use.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

Mirror paint does not work that way. It's not a surface coating, it has to be molecularly smooth and that can't be painted on.

Generally mirror coatings are on the glass itself, and on the backside. The fogged glass has already wrecked the possibility of doing that.   Feel free to obtain actual mirror glass and replace the glass in your cabinets, be careful.